# Как склонить "засметитель управляющего"?

Tags: морфология

Как правильно в дательном падеже написать словосочетание во множественном числе: "Заместитель управляющего"?

Comment: Никто не возражает против использования глагола СКЛОНИТЬ в вопросе?

Answer (score 2):

> Если управляющих с замами не один, а несколько, то тогда отдать заместителям управляющих.

Это весьма спорное предложение. С одной стороны по-русски оно, может, и "красивше будет", но если есть официально утвержденная должность заместитель управляющего, то большой вопрос, будет ли она иметь множественное число в виде "заместители управляющих", а не "заместители управляющего". 
Во всяком случае в советскую эпоху были "первые секретари (райкомов)", но "заместители секретаря по оргработе и идеологии (в комсомоле)". Не уверен, что последние могли быть замами секретар*ей*.
Понимаете, одно дело "паек для жен офицеров", совсем другое "товарищи министров".

Лучше бы все-таки уточнить, насколько официально именование должности.

> Никто не возражает против использования глагола СКЛОНИТЬ в вопросе?

А есть варианты? Предлагаете "просклонять"?

====
Я проанализировал на примере "заместители командующих"/"заместители командующего".
Встречается и так и эдак, разумеется речь только о случаях не допускающих толкование *одного командующего и нескольких заместителей*. Причем бывает так, что встречаются в одном тексте. Все это говорит о не вполне однозначном понимании этого вопроса носителями.

Answer (score 1):

(кому? чему?) заместителю управляющего; мн.ч.: заместителям управляющего

Answer (score 0):

Если управляющий один, а заместителей несколько, в дательном падеже множественного числе будет *отдать заместителям управляющего*.

Если  управляющих с замами не один, а несколько, то тогда *отдать заместителям управляющих*.

Если же вдруг неожиданно, один заместитель на несколько управляющих - *отдать заместителю управляющих*

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно в дательном падеже написать словосочетание во множественном числе: "Заместитель управляющего"?    В данном словосочетании склоняться  (изменяться по падежам и числам) будет только первое слово "заместитель", второе же зависит от первого (тип связи - управление), и всегда будет присоединяться в определённой форме (в данном случае это форма родительного падежа единственного числа).Таким образом, дательный падеж множественного числа будет выглядеть так: "заместителям управляющего". P.S. Я надеюсь, что управляющий всё же один?